# GDI+ Animation Lag in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, animation, visual-studio-2013, timer

So I'm using GDI in VB.Net to animate various bitmaps, all .png files located in my root directory. Right now, I have a large image (~2MB) being painted and animated (panning) in the background of my form, and then I paint UI elements such as buttons and decorations on top. I use transparent picture boxes as substitutes for actual buttons. I have a feature where an animated drop-down menu appears on mousing over, but it stutters and moves very jerkily. It changes position based on a 1ms interval timer for maximum smoothness. Right now, the Form.Paint event is quite large:

```
 Private Sub scrLogin_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'Painting the big picture in the background
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(BGbmp, bgPos.X, bgPos.Y, bgSize.Width, bgSize.Height)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, Ttrim)

    'the trim around the screen
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, Ltrim)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, Rtrim)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, Btrim)

    'the middle panel
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, MPanel)

    ' textbox seperators
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(penWhite, txtsep1.pos1, txtsep1.pos2)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(penWhite, txtsep2.pos1, txtsep2.pos2)

    'textbox icons
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(userbmp, 539, 312, 28, 33)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(lockbmp, 539, 369, 28, 33)

    'login button
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(loginBmp, 539, 452, 167, 46)

    'guest button
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(guestbmp, 705, 452, 122, 46)

    'menu dropdown: position
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushColor, menuBak)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(menuBmp, menuLPos.X, menuLPos.Y, 64, 88)

    'error label text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblerror.Text, lblerror.Font, lblerrorBrush, lblerror.X, lblerror.Y)

    'capslock label text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblcaps.Text, lblcaps.Font, lblcapsBrush, lblcaps.X, lblcaps.Y)

End Sub
```

I'm wondering what could be causing the animation to lag, and I've considered replacing the transparent picture boxes with a mouse click location detector, but I don't want to do it needlessly if its not the problem. Another concern is that I have multiple timers running which might conflict with each other, or maybe the 1ms interval is too short?

This is the code I use to animate the menu:

```
Private Sub Animation()
    Select Case menuLDir
        Case "down.png"
            If menuLPos.Y <> 0 Then
                If menuLPos.Y = -56 Then
                    menuAnimated = True
                    btnSettings.Hide()
                    btnDrop.Hide()
                    menuLPos.Y = -54
                Else
                    menuLPos.Y += 3
                End If
            Else
                menuAnimated = False
                menuLDir = "up.png"
                menuBmp = New Bitmap(menuLoc + menuLDir)
                tmrMenu.Stop()
                btnSettings.Enabled = True
                btnSettings.Show()
                btnDrop.Show()
                btnDrop.Top += 56
                menuState = "open"
            End If
        Case "up.png"
            If menuLPos.Y <> -56 Then
                If menuLPos.Y = 0 Then
                    menuAnimated = True
                    btnSettings.Hide()
                    btnDrop.Hide()
                    menuLPos.Y = -2
                Else
                    menuLPos.Y -= 3
                End If
            Else
                menuAnimated = False
                menuLDir = "down.png"
                menuBmp = New Bitmap(menuLoc + menuLDir)
                tmrMenuDelay.Stop()
                tmrMenu.Stop()
                btnSettings.Enabled = False
                btnSettings.Hide()
                btnDrop.Show()
                btnDrop.Top -= 56
                menuState = "closed"
            End If
    End Select
    menuBak = New Rectangle(menuLPos.X, menuLPos.Y, 64, 88)
    Me.Invalidate(menuRect)
End Sub
```

Where menuRect is the general area of the menu animation so I don't needlessly refresh the entire form. 
I use the DoubleBuffering and AllPaintingInWMPaint control styles, so that isn't the problem.
To keep this question from becoming wayy to long, I'll post the background animation code if its required, but its basically 2 timers - 1 timer to control changing pictures, 1 timer to control the actual panning (also at 1ms tick time). Furthermore, I did my best to ensure that I'm not constantly declaring new bitmaps in the .tick events. I was also thinking of using a single global timer at 1ms tick and running all my .tick events off that, but once again, don't want to rush into anything.
Sorry for the long post!

Comment: You appear to be using `VB.Net`, not `VBA`. I corrected your tags.

Comment: You cannot normally get a 1 msec timer, if you do get one (start Chrome) then nothing particularly good happens when you try to do this a thousand times per second.  Timers normally tick no faster than once every 15.6 msec, pick either 15 or 31 as a Interval.  Still plenty fast enough for the human eye.  And pay attention to the pixel format of the bitmaps, you never get the optimal one.  Which is 32bppPArgb, it can be directly copied to the screen without requiring a conversion, it renders x10 faster.  And make sure they don't get rescaled, very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed my timer ticks to 15 and I can see an improvement already! I was reading up on 32bppPArgb, but I'm not sure how to convert my .png files into 32bppPArgb .bmp files. I tried using this: http://superuser.com/questions/334007/how-to-save-image-as-32-bit-bmp
but I ended up with no transparency and no noticeable improvement in performance. I'm guessing this is because my png files might not have an alpha channel or something.